# Exclude keys from array with continue

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with keys from 0 to n, and i need to exclude the following pattern of keys with continue when the array is iterated:

3,4,8,9,13,14,18,19...

The problem is that i need some kind of formula so that the pattern is not limited only to the numbers above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$exclude = array(3,4,8,9,13,14,18,19);
foreach ( $inputArray as $key => $value ) {
  if ( in_array($key, $exclude) ) {
    continue;
  }

  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = range( 0, $n);
foreach( $array as $i)
{
    if( in_array( $i, array( 3,4,8,9,13,14,18,19)))
        continue;
}
```

Comment: So he can pull out what I set `$array` to and use his own - Seems like a pretty obvious thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
$exclude_keys = array(3,4,9);

for($array as $index => $value) {
    if(false !== array_search($index, $exclude_keys)) {
        //do what you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$exclude_mods = array(3,4,8,9);
foreach ( $inputArray as $key => $value ) {
  if ( in_array($key % 10, $exclude) ) {
    continue;
  }

  // do something
}
```